# Displaying every item of an array as a new line in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

So I have an array called "comments"

```
comments: ["Comment1","Comment2","Comment3"]
```

Now I want to display every item as a new line in HTML

Other stuff from my object I display like this:

```
<p><%= singlegif.get("title") %></p>
```

But obviously putting "comments" in the above code displays them all next to eachother..
Now how do I display one/line?

Comment: That doesn't look like vanilla JavaScript to me.

Comment: Also using Backbone, JQuery and Underscore, sorry!

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array prototype has a function [forEach(callback(element, index, array))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which executes the provided callback once for each element of the array with an assigned value. It is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have been initialized to undefined.

```
var commentsContainer = document.getElementById("demo");
comments: ["Comment1","Comment2","Comment3"];
comments.forEach(function(element, index){
   // create paragraph for each comment
   var elementForComment = document.createElement('p');

   // set text of paragraph
   elementForComment.innerText = element;

   // add paragraph into comments holder.
   commentsContainer.appendChild(elementForComment);
});
```